# Hibernate "in memory" db ...and hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= update

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb

Came across a JEE demo app, where there is no hibernate dialect specified. No db config at all afaics. I assume Hibernate then generates an HSQLDB in memory?

I'm able to go the the "edit pages" of the app.. and add/edit details and save. 
If I un-deploy the server, re start.. all my edits are still present. The "in memory" db looks like it has been persisted somewhere. Whats going on behind the scenes?

I know its something to do with "update".. but I'm wondering simply, where is db file?

```
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: There should be a db config somewhere, there is no default here as far as I know. What the piece of config you are showing says is that the database schemas should be generated when the application starts, but it still needs a database to connect to. It might be that it is an in-memory database backed by files, noticed any new files (probably in project root)?

Comment: Do you restart your app server? Datasources usually are separate from your app and remain "online" even when you redeploy.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replies. I think TomEE is providing support .. see http://tomee.apache.org/common-datasource-configurations.html

Also, I discovered TomEE has a HsqlDB Service on my local host port 9001.

Comment: see http://tomee.apache.org/containers-and-resources.html where for TomEE if it is not specified in persistence.xml HSQLDB setting is default.